# ASP.NET MVC3 Displaying a Title Name from a secondary table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, linq-to-entities

I am doing a tutorial on MVC3 with Code first.  Basically I have 3 tables, Posts, Comments, and Blogs

```
    public class Blog
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string BloggerName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int BlogID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to display a Post in the post page that has a BlogID.  So in my controller at the moment I have the following:-

```
        public ViewResult Index()
    {
        PostViewModel model = new PostViewModel();
        model.Posts = db.Posts.ToList();

        foreach (var item in model.Posts)
        {
            model.Blog = db.Blogs.Where(b => b.ID == item.BlogID).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

with the View having the following :-

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Posts) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateCreated)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Content)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.Blog.Title)
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

What I wish to know is how to get the Blog Title from the Posts.  What do I have to replace this with :-

```
            foreach (var item in model.Posts)
        {
            model.Blog = db.Blogs.Where(b => b.ID == item.BlogID).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

for it to work?

Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a reference to a blog in your Post model instead of a BlogId.

```
public class Post
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
    public ICollection Comments { get; set; }
}
```

So your loop would become:

```
foreach (var item in model.Posts)
{
   item.Blog = db.Blogs.Where(b => b.ID == item.Blog.ID).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Hi Bogdan, I am going to give this as an answer, because it works.  Did not want to add a reference to the Blog in the Post class though since I already have a reference to the Post from the Blog class, but for the moment I think its fine.

Answer (score 1):

After Adding a virtual `Blog` property to your `Post` class you can use the `Blog.Title` in your views.

Comment: yes as such right?  public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }  I did that and now it works

Answer (score 0):

You could directly assign Blog entity to post

```
   foreach (var post in model.Posts)
   {
       post.Blog = db.Blogs.FirstOrDefault(b => b.ID == item.BlogID);
   }
```

Comment: Hi archil, I still have a problem like that since I am still getting only 1 Blog, which is always the last one.  I have a feeling that I cannot do that loop in the controller but i do not know how to do that in the view

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you need to just set the model's `Blog` property to be the blog of one of the posts (e.g. the first post, as all posts belong to the same blog)

```
var post = model.Posts.FirstOrDefault();
model.Blog = post == null ? null : db.Blogs.Where(blog => blog.ID == post.BlogID);
```

Comment: Hi devdigital, post has to be a list since its an index page, so I cannot just get the FirstOrDefault().  I just need the BlogId for every post when its looping